# django regroup grouper name as choices verbose name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Taking simple regroup example from Django documentation:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in country.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ item.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

If country.grouper is a Char field declared in model with choices=CHOICES_FIELD, how can I display it's verbose name in **template** ? Normally i would take [Model.get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) but country.grouper.get_country_list_display of course will not work. 
Is custom template tag only choice ?

Comment: Can you do `regroup cities by get_country_display`?

Comment: For the record...yes, you can use `get_FOO_display` in the grouper as @DanielRoseman suggested

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply have to look at it the other way around!

Use `get_FOO_display` as the grouping field.

> {% regroup cities by get_country_display as country_list %}
>
> {{ country.grouper }} will now display the value fields from the
>   choices set rather than the keys.

(taken verbatim from [djangodocs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/))

Comment: only now i see it was correctly answered in the comments, sorry!